# Guarantee of a PCA dimension estimation

Tags: pca, references, dimensionality-reduction

Given a sample taken from a distribution concentrated near a $d$-dimensional subspace of a Euclidean space, are there published results on the probability that a PCA (principal component analysis) based dimension estimation will correctly return the true dimension $d$?

The precise answer will depend on the setup, but I'm mildly confident that there are results that attempt to answer some formulations of "How well does a PCA-based dimension estimation work?"

---

Let me offer one precise formulation of this question.

Let $\mu$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb R^k$ with a probability density function $f_\mu$ that satisfies:

1. **Confiement near a subspace**. There is a $d$-dimensional vector subspace $\pi \subsetneq \mathbb R^k$ and $\epsilon_\pi>0$ such that $f_\mu(x) = 0$ whenever the distance of $x$ from $\pi$ is greater than $\epsilon_\pi$.
2. **Embodies the subspace**. For some radius $R>0$, there is a constant $C_R$ such that we have $f_\mu(x) > C_R$ whenever $\|x\|<R$ and the distance of $x$ from $\pi$ is less than $\epsilon_\pi$.

Let $X$ be a size $m$ i.i.d. sample drawn from $\mu$. Define the following PCA based dimension estimation: given a tolerance level $\epsilon_{PCA}>0$, whenever the sample $X$ has singular values $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_m$ obtained from PCA, we take the estimated dimension to be $d_{PCA} := m - \min \{ j : \lambda_j^2 + \cdots + \lambda_m^2 < \epsilon_{PCA} \}$.

Now, given any (small) $1>\delta>0$, can we compute a number $N$ that depends on the above tolerance levels $\epsilon_\pi, R, \epsilon_{PCA}, \delta$ such that whenever the sample size $m$ exceeds $N$, there is a $1-\delta$ chance that the dimension estimation returns the true dimension $d_{PCA} = d$?

Note that the formulation I proposed can be tweaked within the qualitative meaning of the original question to become another sensible question. For example, the residual $L^2$ error for dimension estimation can be replaced by $\lambda_j < \epsilon_{PCA}$.

Comment: I think you will need additional constraints to get a general and useful result: they need to imply there's a high chance that a sample, when orthogonally projected to $\pi,$ will include values of norm greater than $\epsilon_\pi$ and those values will span $\pi.$ Your assumption (2) doesn't do this.

Comment: I think the dependence on $C_R$ and the ratio $R/\epsilon_\pi$ can be baked into the formula $N$, if such a formula exists.

Comment: That won't work unless you refine it to focus on the variation parallel to $\pi.$  As it is, (2) and (1) potentially conflict with each other or are nearly redundant.

Comment: oh, I misstated #2. Thanks for pointing that out, I'm going to edit.

Comment: i had to restrict the domain of $f(x)>C$ so that $x$ is within $\epsilon_{PCA}$ of $\pi$.

Comment: That looks a little better but it's not much help.  For instance, a distribution concentrated on the $\epsilon_\pi$ ball *orthogonal* to $\pi$ can have this property provided it puts just a little bit of probability density throughout the ball of radius $R.$ In fact, a criterion based on a density is not a great idea because it's not sufficiently general: you want a criterion that puts actual *probability* near $\pi$ at distances *greater* than $\epsilon_\pi.$

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, and that's why I commented that the number $N$ sought should depend on $C_R, R, \epsilon_\pi$, and in particular $R/\epsilon_\pi$. If $R/\epsilon_\pi$ is very large and $C_R$ is close to its maximum possible value, then $N$ could afford to be smaller than otherwise.

Comment: Alternatively, it may make sense to impose some conditions like $R/\epsilon_\pi > C_1$ and $C_R > C_2(R, \epsilon_\pi)$ and assert that our $N$ exists only when these conditions are satisfied. Either way, the idea is to have large $R/\epsilon_\pi$ and $C_R$.